# To determine if set is open or closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f (t) = t^{2} $ and let $U$ be any nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ Then

a .$ f (U) $ is open

b.  $f (U) $ is closed

c.  $f^{-1}(U)$ is open

d. $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed

Attempt  is that I take any set $U$ consisting of elements say $1,2,3$ then $f (U)$ will have $1 ,4,9$ .Now limit point of $f (U)$ is $\phi $ and hence it is closed but answer seems to be $c$.

Can anyone help where I went wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the answer seems to be b"? If I understood correctly, it is not b.

Comment: What does it mean for $U$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Sorry it was typo .answer is c in my book

Comment: Do you know the definition(s) of a continuous function?

Comment: @TedShifrin so do i have to take open interval

Comment: Yes, any open set in $\Bbb R$ is a union of open intervals.

Comment: @PedroM. Yes i do

Comment: @PedroM.i k ow delta epsilon and sequential definition of continuity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open to any $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ open set.

**Edit:** Consider $f: M \to N$ continuous.

Let $A' \subset N$ be an open set, we want to show that $f^{-1}(A')$ is open. In fact, for each $a \in f^{-1}(A')$, we have that $f(a) \in A'$. By definition of open set, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(f(a), \epsilon) \subset A'$. As $f$ is continuous at $a$, there exists $\delta > 0$ correspondent to $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$f(B(a; \delta)) \subset B(f(a); \epsilon) \subset A'$$

that is, $$B(a;\delta) \subset f^{-1}(A')$$

Then $f^{-1}(A')$ is open.

[image]

Comment: Why is that so.

Comment: It's a result that follows strictly from the definition of a continuous function and open set. And it's a "if, and only, if" result.

Comment: Can you explain it intuitively

Comment: Sure, wait a second.

Comment: There you have it.

Comment: So, do you have any questions?

Comment: No thankyou for explanation

Comment: @aAaron Maroja can it be justified by taking graph in xy plane instead of ball

Comment: It could, it wouldn't be in $xy$-plane since we're dealing with $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $N=\mathbb{R}$. But we could perfectly see this over lines, where an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$ is an open interval on the real line.

Comment: Doesthat reduces to normal delta epsilon definition

Comment: Yes, it does. With the induced $|.|$ metric.

Answer (score 2):

Statement c is of course true, because the function is continuous.

If you know that the function is continuous (at every point), then take an open set $U$. In order to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, we need to see that, for $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, there exists $\delta>0$ with 
$$
B(x,\delta)=\{r\in\mathbb{R}:|r-x|<\delta\}\subseteq f^{-1}(U).
$$
Since $f$ is continuous at $x$ and $U$ is open, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
B(f(x),\varepsilon)\subseteq U.
$$
Now apply the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity and the problem is solved: the required $\delta>0$ is exactly the one provided by the continuity condition.

Why is the function continuous? By general theorems: the product of continuous functions is continuous; the identity function $t\mapsto t$ is obviously continuous.

---

The other statements are false, in the sense that for each one you can find a particular $U$ such that the condition doesn't hold.

For a consider $U=\mathbb{R}$. Hint: $f(U)=[0,\infty)$

For b consider $U=(0,\infty)$. Hint: $f(U)=(0,\infty)$

For d consider $U=(0,1)$. Hint: $f^{-1}(U)=(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$

Comment: Can you please explain more

Comment: @godonichia What, in particular?

Comment: Anyone of your sub answer .

Comment: I am not able to see solution but your answer is appropriate atbmy level

Comment: I meant with U you gave how the condition is violated that i am not able to see

Comment: @godonichia Just prove the hints. Then…